# How to do automatic MySQL database Backup?

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups

How to do automatic MySQL Database backup? Is it possible? Can anyone help?

I have a database name 'contacts'. 
How can create an automatic backup for it?

Comment: That depends.  For a typical server running linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP (LAMP) you set up a cron job to run a script that runs mysqldump.  A Google search will explain that.  For a stand-alone server at for example Amazon Web Services, they document how to control backups.

Comment: thank you @dave-s for ur quick response.
I am working on windows 10, and using XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing that you are using an unix-like OS. You need to do two steps

**Backup your current database**

First you need to know how to use mysqldump. This should be a good start point.

```
mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > full-backup-$(date +%F).sql -u root -p
```

**Cron your mysqldump**

You need to create a file with your credentials. Something like this

```
sudo nano /home/example_user/.mylogin.cnf

[client]
user = root
password = MySQL root user's password

chmod 600 /home/example_user/.mylogin.cnf
```

Then, you have to add this line to your cron

```
sudo nano crontab -e
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/home/example_user/.my.cnf -u root --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --all-databases > full-backup-$(date +\%F).sql
```

And that's all.

Source: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/use-mysqldump-to-back-up-mysql-or-mariadb/

Comment: Thank u @fvildoso for ur quick response, I am working on windows 10, and using XAMPP.

Comment: @Prodip in that case you could substitute the Cron part for Windows Task Scheduler

Comment: @ADyson ok then, i'll try. Thanks again for the recommendation.

Comment: @ProdipKirtania you need to add xampp/mysql/bin to the PATH, then you will be able to use mysqldump on a script. Finally, you'll have to add that script to windows task scheduler